□(P→ □Q) → P → □Q validity in Propositional Temporal Logic
How can i analyse the validity in Propositional Temporal Logic (PTL) of this formula, Is that necessary to use the Kripke structure?

No. You could also give a formal proof, using the axioms and rules of LTL found eg in Manna & Pnueli's book (the first in the 3-volume series).
